# WACK Error after Converting WPF to UWP using Desktop App Converter

Tags: wpf, uwp, windows-store-apps, desktop, wack

I was trying to convert my awesome WPF app to UWP using the Desktop App Converter.
I converted the app using DesktopAppConverter successfully, installed on my local Windows 10 machine and works like a charm. All good so far.

However when I tried the Windows App Certification process, it fails with the below error.

- API _amsg_exit in msvcr100.dll is not supported for this application type.
- API _cexit in msvcr100.dll is not supported for this application type.
- API _commode in msvcr100.dll is not supported for this application type.

I actually use many essential functionalities via a CPP library which was created using some python code (which I don't have source code for).

(I guess "msvcr100.dll" is Microsoft C++ Re-distributable Package? )

Can any one help resolve this issue?

Comment: This may be of use https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/07/07/using-visual-c-runtime-in-centennial-project/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WACK tool in the Windows 10 AU SDK is not applicable to Desktop Bridge app. You don't need to run it prior to submission. The error you are seeing here you can ignore.

Upcoming new versions of the SDK will have an updated WACK tool with specific support for Desktop Bridge apps.

Thanks!

Comment: Wow! Thanks a bunch! I never knew that. Let me try publishing then, and will come back here with what I find. However do you have a direct link stating just what you said?

Comment: Let me add something to MSDN that states this. For now, you can take my work - I am the Program Manager for the Desktop Bridge :-)  I do think I have mentioned it in this video as I talk about WACK support coming soon, towards the end - if that's official enough :-)  https://youtu.be/2nnQzDZCi64

Comment: Apologies. I did not really get a chance to watch the video and will do this weekend. Thank you!

Comment: Now I start publishing & this is what I see
1 - You need to accept the Centennial Early Adopter Program before you can submit this app.
and the link https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/account/agreements?agreementType=Centennial
shows only a "Back" button

2 - Your developer account doesn’t have permission to submit apps converted with the Desktop Bridge at this time.

My app is not yet published to any website yet. However this page has a mandatory field for app website. Any Help?

Comment: Just watched the video awesome. Thanks a bunch!
Just was wondering when the MVA course will be available (mid March already?)
Also, it will be great if you could answer the above Qs?
Finally, I am interested to convert my existing UI to UWP XAML UI (as you mentioned in the Video). Any resource as to how to do that?

Comment: Yes, your account needs to be enabled for this program. Send me an email [swick at microsoft.com] and we'll work through the process.

Comment: Sure. Thanks a bunch! Let us know if you know the date of the Virtual Academy course availability.

Comment: We are putting the final finishing touches on the MVA course right now. Hoping it will go live next week.